# A generalization of the Archimedean circle

Tags: reference-request, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

I proposed a generalization of the [Archimedean circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_circle) : In this figure $M$ is the midpoint of $AB$, $DE$; $(G)$, $(H)$, $(M)$ are the semicircles. Then two yellow circles are congruent.

**Question**: Is this result know?

[image]

Comment: Dr. Floor van Lamoen say me that: He saw it here in an article by Hiroshi Okumura: https://hrcak.srce.hr/file/197554